# Which AWS resources benefit from bandwidth transfer to AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lightsail

Lightsail lets you connect to AWS resources, such as an Amazon RDS database, through virtual private cloud (VPC) peering. 
Does all bandwidth associated with VPC has free bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

you are not charged for data transfer within the subnet, for accessing any other resources there will be a charge.